# I need images/cliparts/icons for mathematical symbols

Tags: icons, symbols

I need to add icons (16x16) for my application. The icons must be showing images of +,-,x,%,<,>,!= and symbols like that. Is there any site where i can get it? Or any software which can quickly help me generate them. I'm bad in designing them.

Also suggest me a site where i can get free collection of Icons or Images, (i can convert images to icons).

Comment: for the second part of your question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you will like these. I believe most are 16x16 as well:

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematical_icons

Comment: the link is awesome! thanks. but i was unable to find it for "<", ">", "!=". Any help on it?

Comment: I could find the '<' and '>' icons here: http://www.freeiconsweb.com/free_developers_icons.html but I haven't found the != icon, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your favorite word processor (or any software able to show text with wanted attributes, eg. your Web browser!) to show these symbols with needed size, colors, font, etc.

Then you can use a screen capture software to do a snapshot, then convert the image to icon.

Or just use an icon editor able to show text...

Answer (score 0):

glyFX has a set of ["Character Tile" icons](http://www.glyfx.com/shop/detail/vistacharacter/) with an icons for 212 unicode characters in different colours. I think it includes all the characters you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you render fonts into images?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Arrows

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Greek_and_Coptic

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Letterlike_Symbols

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Mathematical_Operators

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Miscellaneous_Mathematical_Symbols-A

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Miscellaneous_Mathematical_Symbols-B

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Miscellaneous_Technical

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Supplemental_Arrows-A

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Supplemental_Arrows-B

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Supplemental_Mathematical_Operators